# I want to use Subview like an alertview

Tags: iphone

I have an application , that has one mainviewcontroller with some button.When i click setting button in my application , i have added onesubview to MainView ([self.view addSubview:SettingSubView];)

Its work fine.subview frame width=200 and height=200.That subviews shows front of the mainview with center place adjusted.What i want is when subview is added to mainview, that time i dont want user interaction with mainview.Thats trick should be done in UIAlertView.When alertview is shown we cant able to touch anything in the mainview.i want to do same thing using subview.

One more thing is i dont want to add this subview as alert subview.

Is it possible ?

thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making your SettingSubview a direct subviews of the main view, place a view in-between.  This view should cover the entire main view and have a transparent (clearColor) background color.

Main view
-transparent view
--SettingSubview view

Answer (score 0):

Try using UIActionSheet that would do, as i have done the same for one of my app